# Concatenate dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate the 2 dataframes below such that:

I will have a new dataframe with headers:

Timestamp   adjusted close    reportedEPS     estimatedEPS

and the reportedEPS and estimatedEPS will be constant according to the respective values from:

1 jan - 31 mar, 1 apr - 30 june, 1 july - 30 sep, 1 oct - 31 dec of the timestamps?

The 2 dataframes:

https://gyazo.com/38b50a3d7eb138521c89ac93e31b948d

https://gyazo.com/d0ad4c884bf818d0e32d50134de08b39

Comment: please do not post external links of dataframes, instead [create small dataframes to reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following explanation and sample code from [this link](https://datacarpentry.org/python-ecology-lesson/05-merging-data/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20the%20concat,to%20see%20how%20this%20works.&text=When%20we%20concatenate%20DataFrames%2C%20we,DataFrame%20UNDER%20the%20first%20one.).

> When we concatenate DataFrames, we need to specify the axis. `axis=0`
> tells pandas to stack the second DataFrame UNDER the first one. It
> will automatically detect whether the column names are the same and
> will stack accordingly. `axis=1` will stack the columns in the second
> DataFrame to the RIGHT of the first DataFrame. To stack the data
> vertically, we need to make sure we have the same columns and
> associated column format in both datasets. When we stack horizontally,
> we want to make sure what we are doing makes sense (i.e. the data are
> related in some way).

```
# Stack the DataFrames on top of each other
vertical_stack = pd.concat([survey_sub, survey_sub_last10], axis=0)

# Place the DataFrames side by side
horizontal_stack = pd.concat([survey_sub, survey_sub_last10], axis=1)
```